# Storing nested objects using codenameone storage

Tags: codenameone

I am using Codenameone Storage to store a hashtable. The Hashtable contains a vector of hash tables. The hash table in the vector contains different objects including other hash tables. When I try to save by using

Storage.getInstance.write("myCache",hash);

I get this error

java.io.IOException: Object type not supported: java.util.LinkedList value: [com.apiomat.frontend.reportyamain.Service@65d9e279]
    at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Util.java:367)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Util.java:213)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Util.java:200) .....

Is it that some objects or objects types cannot be written to Storage? Are there specific types of objects that can be written?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Vector and Hashtable at this time other util classes aren't supported by default for persistence.

Comment: But this is not a until class. It really is just a pojo with collection fields.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. java.util.LinkedList is not supported. Wow. I will need to do a lot of refactoring of my code.